# Why does iterative deepening A star not need to test for duplicate states?

Tags: algorithm, search

Iterative deepening A star (ID A*) is a memory bounded search. My question is that when we reach a new state `s'` from an open state `s` in ID A*, why we do not test whether `s'` is already in the "open states" or "closed states"?

For some problem, e.g.: sudoku, as state will never be reached twice, because the "graph of states of the problem" is a tree. However, for other problem, e.g.: an 8-puzzle, it is likely to reach a state again and again. So, it should definitely be tested whether a state is already "visited" (either in the open or closed states) or not.

If such tests have to be done, then ID A* is not memory bounded anymore because a large hash table of all possible states has to be stored.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about algorithms  not specific to programming.

Comment: Wait. What do you mean by off-topic? There are "algorithm" and "search" tags. How can you say algorithm is not a part of programming?

Comment: Personally, I think this is on-topic (although perhaps a better fit for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com.) Read the Help topic [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @DanielA.White - From the [Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"if your question generally covers ... • a software algorithm ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!"_ And [IDA*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA*) is most definitely a software algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't test whether s' is a duplicate in order to keep the memory profile small. In general, IDA<sup>*</sup> will, in fact, expand the same state multiple times.

Comment: Then, do you mean that, even in a single run of search with a specific f-limit (the limit of evaluation function), a state will be visited many times? I know that a state is going to be visited in many rounds. But intuitively., it should not be visited many times in a single run of search.

Comment: @user2697964 - IDA* only remembers nodes on the current path. It will not expand a state that is its own ancestor. However, if a state is reachable from multiple paths, it might expand that state several times, even within a single f-limit.

Comment: @user2697964To prevent re-searching nodes, IDA* can be paired with a transposition table, which uses main memory to cache previously searched nodes. If a node has been encountered before and searched to a depth greater or equal to the current search depth, its cached value can be used instead. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_table

Answer (score 1):

AI-programming is often about trying many different tweaking of algorithms to find the one that best fits your need. If it is very likely that a new state already has been visited, then it might be a performance improvement to add the extra overhead of determining whether a state has already been visited. But there might be many other variables to consider, e.g. how the algorithm fits the problem, your memory available, your processing power, scale-ability. I think being a good AI-programmer means that you know the pros and cons of the different algorithms and have seen how many different problems affect the performance of each algorithm. I do not think you should think that an algorithm like ID A* is limited to not consider if a state has already been reached. If you think it will perform better by considering reentered states, try it out and see if improves your solution.